# Generate class inside a subfolder using t4 template

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, t4, dbcontext

I am generating context of my entities using T4 templates. When t4 template file runs, it adds generated files in project root directory. What I want is that generated files are placed under a sub folder. If sub-folder is not present then create folder and then place generated files inside that. And if file is present then new file doesn't generate.

I am new to t4 templates. I replaced

```
fileManager.StartNewFile(entity.Name + ".cs");
```

to

```
fileManager.StartNewFile("SubFolder\" + entity.Name + ".cs");
```

When I run it, file is created in SubFolder (Open folder using windows explorer) but project is not aware of it. And if there is no folder then strange behavior occurs. What am I missing?

Comment: What I do is placing the template in the said subfolder. That might not work for you but in my cases it gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

better to put the tt file and the model classes in the same folder. just change the inputFile path, like inputFile = @"..\Model1.edmx" (if your edmx file is in the root folder).

another thing may need to be changed is the namespace, by default it is Code.VsNamespaceSuggestion(), it will add the subfolder name to the namesapce. like "ClassLibrary1.SubFolder". It may cause problems. you can hard code the namespace like namespaceName = "ClassLibrary1".